# Root category page is throwing a 404

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.4

My root category page is showing as a 404. I want to be able to use it to filter products from the subnav (under fabrics option in top menu), however I cannot get the page to load. The url key is set to all-collections, and I have re-indexed and cleared the cache.

Root category:
http://jimdickens.mattmacleod.co.uk/all-collections.html

Filtered example:
http://jimdickens.mattmacleod.co.uk/all-collections.html?recommended_usage=220

Category is enabled and set to Anchor.

Thnx!

Comment: Root categories are not accessible from frontend. You need to create another category if you want those to appear on frontend. https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/category-root.html

Comment: Ugh. RTFM. Thanks.